# Why can't this simple scala example be compiled?

Tags: scala

```
class X extends Map[String, String] {
    def x(): X = { X() } // can't be compiled
}
```

can't be compiled, the error is:

```
<console>:6: error: not found: value X
def x(): X = { X() } // can't be compiled
```

Why is X not found? I can't see how to correct it.

---

UPDATE:

I know the reason now. What I want to do is create a class which extends `HashMap`, since `Map()` will return an instance of `HashMap`, so I thought I can just extends `Map`. Now, the correct code should be:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
class X extends HashMap[String, String] {
    def x(): X = { new X() }
}
```

Comment: Kevin Wright has a *very* good reply wrt the collection extending. Consider creating another SO question just focusing on just that (extending/creating Scala 2.8 collections) particularly issue to "un-bury" it.

Comment: @pst, good suggestion, but for now, I'm too new to scala, I don't even know how to ask that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `new X()` instead of `X()` -- you'll get another error, but it'll set you on the right track I believe.

In the latter case it is trying to invoke apply upon the *expression* denoted by `X` (e.g. imagine where `X` is defined as `object X` or `val X`) and *not* trying to invoke the constructor for *class* X.

Happy coding.

Comment: thank you. Could you tell me how to do it correctly? I'm new to scala, and have tried a lot just now.

Answer (score 13):

Can I recommend that you try a different approach?

Extending the collection library is one of the more advanced things you can do in Scala. To do the job properly you need a deep understanding of higher-kinded types, inference, variance, implicits, and the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism. This is not a light-hearted task to be taken on by a beginner.

On the other hand, it's incredibly rare that you'll ever actually need to extend a collection.

Go back to first principles... What problem are you trying to solve for which you think the correct approach is to extend `HashMap`?  I can virtually guarantee that there's a much better way to do it in Scala.

**UPDATE Mk.II**

*This answer previously contained a description of the collection framework `CanBuildFrom` logic.  Following @soc's suggestion, I've now migrated that part of the answer to an [FAQ question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200505/how-are-scala-collections-able-to-return-the-correct-collection-type-from-a-map-o)*

Comment: thank you for your kind advice. I found it's hard to use a class which extends `HashMap` to work together with other classes, so I gave up. I'm too newbie, that I can't ask you more about it. Let me take more time to learn scala. Thanks again.

Comment: Very nice. Consider posting this as a 'FAQ Question' -- it is buried in this post.

Comment: @soc - better still, I'll just collect all my answers on stack overflow and put them in a book :)

Comment: Great answer, but minor stylistic nitpick: in one paragraph you say "Ignoring the XxxLike traits briefly, each tier in that hierarchy adds a little bit of functionality" but then in the next paragraph describe how TraversableLike implements map. It sounds like you're first saying there's no important functionality in the xxxLike traits, but then directly contradicting that statement. That said... very well done, sir! ;~)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but the reason it doesn't compile is that there is no field, function or method called 'X', and there is no module 'X' with an 'apply()' method.

"How to correct it?"

Clarify what you are trying to achieve.