# How are Scala collections able to return the correct collection type from a map operation?

Tags: scala, collections

*Note: This is an FAQ, asked specifically so I can answer it myself, as this issue seems to come up fairly often and I want to put it in a location where it can (hopefully) be easily found via a search*

As prompted by a comment on my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189984/why-cant-this-simple-scala-example-be-compiled/5190950#5190950)

---

For example:

```
"abcde" map {_.toUpperCase} //returns a String
"abcde" map {_.toInt} // returns an IndexedSeq[Int]
BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {2*} // returns a BitSet
BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {_.toString} // returns a Set[String]
```

Looking in the scaladoc, all of these use the `map` operation inherited from `TraversableLike`, so how come it's always able to return the most specific valid collection? Even `String`, which provides `map` via an implicit conversion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala 2.8 collections design tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial)

Comment: Skipping the italic part at first, I was deeply confused for a moment. James, this specific question is not really answered in the linked post. It is merely stated that implicits have sth to do with it. Assuming that Kevin wants to be much more elaborate, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @James - it's a slightly different take, I'm focusing more specifically on the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism

Comment: That's quite a stretch to call it "able to return the most appropriate collection."

Comment: @Tony: If we allow that the definition of "appropriate" is relative to the context in which entities are allowed to move, then the statement becomes accurate.  *Given* that the result of an operation on a collection is going to be another collection, it is fair to say that the most "appropriate" collection it could be is another collection of that same type if possible, and the most-specific alternative when not.  Logan is right though, this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Fair point, the term "appropriate" is overloaded and I expected readers to infer the correct meaning. Question now updated with more specific phrasing.

Comment: Actually, I've changed my mind. "appropriate" isn't overloaded; it's just highly-generic, and the correct definition should be inferred from the context in which it's used. Ironically, these are *exactly* the same properties that so many of us seek out as being desirable in our source code.

Comment: I'd love to know the motivation for the lone downvoter - it's bad form to do so without justification.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Scala collections are clever things...

Internals of the collection library is one of the more advanced topics in the land of Scala. It involves higher-kinded types, inference, variance, implicits, and the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism - all to make it incredibly generic, easy to use, and powerful from a user-facing perspective. Understanding it from the point-of-view of an API designer is not a light-hearted task to be taken on by a beginner.

On the other hand, it's incredibly rare that you'll ever actually need to work with collections at this depth.

So let us begin...

With the release of Scala 2.8, the collection library was completely rewritten to remove duplication, a great many methods were moved to just one place so that ongoing maintenance and the addition of new collection methods would be far easier, but it also makes the hierarchy harder to understand.

Take `List` for example, this inherits from (in turn)

- `LinearSeqOptimised`
- `GenericTraversableTemplate`
- `LinearSeq`
- `Seq`
- `SeqLike`
- `Iterable`
- `IterableLike`
- `Traversable`
- `TraversableLike`
- `TraversableOnce`

That's quite a handful! So why this deep hierarchy? Ignoring the `XxxLike` traits briefly, each tier in that hierarchy adds a little bit of functionality, or provides a more optimised version of inherited functionality (for example, fetching an element by index on a `Traversable` requires a combination of `drop` and `head` operations, grossly inefficient on an indexed sequence).  Where possible, all functionality is pushed as far up the hierarchy as it can possibly go, maximising the number of subclasses that can use it and removing duplication.

`map` is just one such example.  The method is implemented in `TraversableLike` (Though the `XxxLike` traits only really exist for library designers, so it's generally considered to be a method on `Traversable` for most intents and purposes - I'll come to that part shortly), and is widely inherited.  It's possible to define an optimised version in some subclass, but it must still conform to the same signature.  Consider the following uses of `map` (as also mentioned in the question):

```
"abcde" map {_.toUpperCase} //returns a String
"abcde" map {_.toInt} // returns an IndexedSeq[Int]
BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {2*} // returns a BitSet
BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {_.toString} // returns a Set[String]
```

In each case, the output is of the same type as the input wherever possible.  When it's not possible, superclasses of the input type are checked until one is found that *does* offer a valid return type. Getting this right took a lot of work, especially when you consider that `String` isn't even a collection, it's just implicitly convertible to one.

So how is it done?

One half of the puzzle is the `XxxLike` traits (I *did* say I'd get to them...), whose main function is to take a `Repr` type param (short for "Representation") so that they'll know the true subclass actually being operated on.  So e.g. `TraversableLike` is the same as `Traversable`, but abstracted over the `Repr` type param.  This param is then used by the second half of the puzzle; the `CanBuildFrom` type class that captures source collection type, target element type and target collection type to be used by collection-transforming operations.

It's easier to explain with an example!

BitSet defines an implicit instance of `CanBuildFrom` like this:

```
implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[BitSet, Int, BitSet] = bitsetCanBuildFrom
```

When compiling `BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {2*}`, the compiler will attempt an implicit lookup of `CanBuildFrom[BitSet, Int, T]`

This is the clever part... There's only one implicit in scope that matches the first two type parameters. The first parameter is `Repr`, as captured by the `XxxLike` trait, and the second is the element type, as captured by the current collection trait (e.g. `Traversable`). The `map` operation is then also parameterised with a type, this type `T` is inferred based on the third type parameter to the `CanBuildFrom` instance that was implicitly located. `BitSet` in this case.

So the first two type parameters to `CanBuildFrom` are inputs, to be used for implicit lookup, and the third parameter is an output, to be used for inference.

`CanBuildFrom` in `BitSet` therefore matches the two types `BitSet` and `Int`, so the lookup will succeed, and inferred return type will also be `BitSet`.

When compiling `BitSet(1,2,3,4) map {_.toString}`, the compiler will attempt an implicit lookup of `CanBuildFrom[BitSet, String, T]`.  This will fail for the implicit in BitSet, so the compiler will next try its superclass - `Set` - This contains the implicit:

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Set[A]] = setCanBuildFrom[A]
```

Which matches, because Coll is a type alias that's initialised to be `BitSet` when `BitSet` derives from `Set`. The `A` will match anything, as `canBuildFrom` is parameterised with the type `A`, in this case it's inferred to be `String`... Thus yielding a return type of `Set[String]`.

So to correctly implement a collection type, you not only need to provide a correct implicit of type `CanBuildFrom`, but you also need to ensure that the concrete type of that of that collection is supplied as the `Repr` param to the correct parent traits (for example, this would be `MapLike` in the case of subclassing `Map`).

`String` is a little more complicated as it provides `map` by an implicit conversion. The implicit conversion is to `StringOps`, which subclasses `StringLike[String]`, which ultimately derives `TraversableLike[Char,String]` - `String` being the `Repr` type param.

There's also a `CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]` in scope so that the compiler knows that when mapping the elements of a `String` to `Char`s, then the return type should also be a string. From this point onwards, the same mechanism is used.

Comment: +1 for a very cool explanation of Scala's type-preserving collection transformations. Also, very nice use of StackOverflow. Back in Ye Olde Podcasts, Jeff repeatedly mentioned this use case (phrasing an insight as a question and then immediately answering it), and I have seen it much too seldom.

Comment: @Jörg Check Scala questions more often, then. :-) I have used it myself on some occasions, and I think I saw others do it too. I guess we scalazzi like explaining things! :-)

Comment: I have been banging my head at why trying to `breakOut` an `Iterator` to a `List` would not compile. After reading this post and @DanielC.Sobral [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout) I finally realised that a) I do actually understand how this all works and b) `Iterator.map(...)` does not take an implicit CanBuildFrom in a second parameter list... why is that?

Answer (score 8):

The [*Architecture of Scala Collections*](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html) online pages have a detailed explanation geared towards the practical aspects of creating new collections based on the 2.8 collection design.

Quote:

> "What needs to be done if you want to integrate a new collection class, so that it can profit from all predefined operations at the right types? On the next few pages you'll be walked through two examples that do this."

It uses as example a collection for encoding RNA sequences and one for Patricia trie. Look for the *Dealing with map and friends* section for the explanation of what to do to return the appropriate collection type.