# Creating typed collection

Tags: scala

II am trying to understand Scala collections by adding a new collection as follows:

```
class NewColl[V](values:Vector[V],someOtherParams)
extends IndexedSeq[V] with IndexedSeqLike[V, NewColl[V]] {

  def fromSeq[V](seq: Seq[V]): NewColl[V] = ...

  override def newBuilder[V]: Builder[V, NewColl[V]] =
    new ArrayBuffer[V] mapResult fromSeq[V]
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
overriding method newBuilder in trait TraversableLike
   of type => scala.collection.mutable.Builder[V,NewColl[V]];
method newBuilder in trait GenericTraversableTemplate
   of type => scala.collection.mutable.Builder[V,IndexedSeq[V]] has incompatible type
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do in similar cases is to look at what the standard library does in similar cases. Looking at concrete subclasses of `IndexedSeq` they seem to mix in `GenericTraversableTemplate`. With that in mind, reworking your code to use it I get:

```
import collection.mutable._
import collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate
import collection.generic.GenericCompanion

class NewColl[V](values:Vector[V]) extends IndexedSeq[V] with 
    GenericTraversableTemplate[V, NewColl] {

  def fromSeq[V](seq: Seq[V]): NewColl[V] = new NewColl(Vector(seq: _*))

  override def companion: GenericCompanion[NewColl] = new GenericCompanion[NewColl]() {
    def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, NewColl[A]] = new Builder[A, NewColl[A]] {
      val elems = new ArrayBuffer[A]()
      def +=(a:A) = { elems += a; this } 
      def clear() { elems.clear }
      def result(): NewColl[A] = fromSeq(elems)
    }
  }

}
```

(with *someOtherParams* removed for clarity)

Note that there are other questions on SO related to building classes on the scala 2.8 collection framework. For instance [5200505](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200505/how-are-scala-collections-able-to-return-the-correct-collection-type-from-a-map-o) which points to one of my favorite document [*The Architecture of Scala Collections*](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html). Also recently, Josh Suereth wrote a [blog entry](http://suereth.blogspot.com/2011/06/generic-quicksort-in-scala.html) on creating your own collection class.

Comment: the result of a `map` is still IndexedSeq instead of NewColl!

Comment: @teucer, you need to provide a `CanBuildFrom`, see http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_5.html. I recommend skimming/reading *The Architecture of Scala Collections* and then trying to implement your collection. Doing the reverse is just more challenging for no reason.