# How does scala.collection.TraversableView.NoBuilder work?

Tags: scala, collections

I've read

- [Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)
- [How are Scala collections able to return the correct collection type from a map operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200505/how-are-scala-collections-able-to-return-the-correct-collection-type-from-a-map?rq=1)
- And of course, [Is the Scala 2.8 collections library a case of "the longest suicide note in history"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist)

I think I have a bit of a handle on `canBuildFrom`.

But then I look at the source for `TraversableView`, and I see this:

```
object TraversableView {
  class NoBuilder[A] extends Builder[A, Nothing] {
    def +=(elem: A): this.type = this
    def iterator: Iterator[A] = Iterator.empty
    def result() = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TraversableView.Builder.result")
    def clear() {}
  }
  type Coll = TraversableView[_, C] forSome {type C <: Traversable[_]}
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, TraversableView[A, Traversable[_]]] =
    new CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, TraversableView[A, Traversable[_]]] {
      def apply(from: Coll) = new NoBuilder
      def apply() = new NoBuilder
    }
}
```

How does `TraversableView` even work like this? It seems like there is nothing happening here (`NoBuilder` seems aptly named).

Could someone explain (1) the function that `NoBuilder` plays here and (2) how `map`, `filter`, etc. can still work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NoBuilder` exists so that clients can treat Scala views as if they were normal collections when transforming them. It is a dummy implementation that allows `TraversableView` to extend `Traversable` and call methods like `map` without knowing if the collection is a view or a normal collection.

#### Longer explanation

When you call `map`, `flatMap` or `scanLeft` (called *transformer* operations) on a Scala collection, a `CanBuildFrom` implicit argument is automatically resolved. The `CanBuildFrom` object is an abstract factory for `Builder` objects.

Most Scala collections use `Builders` to add elements with `+=` and produce a new collection by calling `result` on the buidler. E.g. given a builder object `b`, `map` does this:

```
def map[S, That](f: T => S)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, S, That]) = {
  val b: Builder[S, That] = cbf(this)
  for (x <- this) b += f(x)
  b.result
}
```

Transformer operations on views do not instantiate a new collection. Instead, they create a lazy view. For example, `map` does something like this:

```
def map[S, That](f: T => S)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, S, That]) = new TraversableView {
  def foreach[U](forFunc: T => U): Unit = for (x <- self) forFunc(f(x))
}
```

Note that a `map` on a view has the same signature, but does not really call `+=` and `result` on the builder. Thus, the `NoBuilder` used in views does not really need to store elements or return a collection, it is just a dummy whose methods are never called.

The same signature allows writing this in client code:

```
def foo(xs: Traversable[Int]) = xs.map(_ + 1)
foo(0 until 100)
foo((0 until 100).view)
```